# different buttons perform different actions

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

I'm trying to run an experiment and I can't seem to find anywhere that offers any help.

My experiment is a set of multiple buttons that each print a separate line of text in a text box on a SwingView.

I have multiple buttons, but each button is leading to the same ActionListener.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TextArea1 implements ActionListener{
JTextArea text;
int numClick = 0;

public static void main(String[] args){
    TextArea1 gui = new TextArea1();
    gui.go();
    }

public void go(){
    JFrame aFrame = new JFrame();

    JPanel aPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel aPanel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel aPanel3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel aPanel4 = new JPanel();
    JPanel aBoard = new JPanel();

    JButton aButton = new JButton("Just Click it");
    JButton aButton1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton aButton2 = new JButton("2");
    ...
    JButton aButton9 = new JButton("9");        

    aPanel2.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    aPanel3.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    aPanel4.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    aBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    aBoard.add(aButton1);
    aBoard.add(aButton2);
    ...
    aBoard.add(aButton9);

    aButton.addActionListener(this);
    aButton1.addActionListener(this);
    aButton2.addActionListener(this);
    ...
    aButton9.addActionListener(this);

    text = new JTextArea(3,20);
    text.setLineWrap(true);

    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(text);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    aPanel.add(scroller);

    aFrame.getContentPane() .add(BorderLayout.EAST, aPanel2);
    aFrame.getContentPane() .add(BorderLayout.WEST, aPanel3);
    aFrame.getContentPane() .add(BorderLayout.NORTH, aPanel4);
    aFrame.getContentPane() .add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, aPanel);
    aFrame.getContentPane() .add(BorderLayout.CENTER, aBoard);

    aFrame.setSize(350,300);
    aFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
    numClick++;
    text.append("button clicked " + numClick + "time(s) \n");
    }
}
```

This is what i've written so far. I've gotten the code to print out new text every time a button is clicked. but the code doesn't differentiate between each button, so it doesn't matter if it's button1 or button2, the same situation happens

Comment: I have a crazy idea: use different a `ActionListener` for each different button.

Comment: Write different `ActionListener` classes for your buttons that you want to do different things.

Comment: Consider taking a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: `((JButton) ev.getSource()).getText()` and use `switch` (or, `if-else`)

Comment: In the action performed method, call `System.out.println(ev.getActionCommand());` and inspect the output..

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the same `ActionListener` for all the `JButton`s, then use

```
aButton.setActionCommand("First");
```

Similarly, set `ActionCommands` for the other `JButton`s too and in the `actionPerformed` method,use

```
if(ev.getActionCommand.equals("First"))
    // aButton was pressed as the actionCommand of it is "First"
```

And similarly add other `if`s to check if other `JButton`s was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), this allows you to isolate the functionality for each button, but also to make it re-usable for other things like key bindings and menus.

```
public class JustClickIt extends AbstractAction {  
    public JustClickIt() {
        putValue(NAME, "Just Click It");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // Make it happen
    }
}
```

Then just apply it to the button...

```
JButton aButton = new JButton(new JustClickIt());
```